# Using .c/.h images exported with gimp in SDL

Tags: c, image, gimp

I wonder if someone has any idea if it's possible to use .c or .h images with SDL exported in gimp. I know there is .xpm but I can't somehow enable transparency for .xpm images.

I do know there are some complex ways to render .c/.h files in C, but I'd rather use SDL, since I'm trying to learn it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gimp header export function use it's own format, providing a macro used to uncrunch it, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875192/explanation-of-header-pixel-in-gimp-created-c-header-file-of-an-xpm-image)

you can load raw data buffer into a sdl surface using [SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom)

as you want load pictures into sdl, i can suggest you simply convert pictures files as a C array, not as raw pictures but still as bmp or png,

you can use [this tool](http://procvor.free.fr/download/bin/mbin2h.rar) to convert any binary file to a .h

this will provide you file size as a define and a pointer to the file buffer,

```
#define dataSize 93722

unsigned char data[dataSize] = {
    'B',    'M',    0x1A,   'n',    0x1,    0x0,    0x0,    0x0,
    0x0,    0x0,    'z',    0x0,    0x0,    0x0,    'l',    0x0,
...
};
```

as it's sdl you will need to convert the buffer to a [SDL_RWops](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWFromMem) structure,

```
SDL_RWops * z = SDL_RWFromMem(data,dataSize);
```

now for load this structure into a fresh sdl surface you need to use *_RW functions,

if you plain to use classic bmp files, it's directly supported in sdl with [SDL_LoadBMP_RW](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LoadBMP_RW)
the same thing exist in [sdl image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image.html#Loading) for all supported pictures types,

```
SDL_Surface * titleScreen = SDL_LoadBMP_RW(z,1);
```

for define the transparent color value of a sdl surface, you can use the [SDL_SetColorKey](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetColorKey) function

```
SDL_SetColorKey( titleScreen, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, 10);
```

if you want a concrete example, [check this old source](https://github.com/r043v/falldown.wdows.sdl), it's uncrunch & load several bmp pictures into sdl from an in memory rar file,

as raw data or bmp are not crunched your executable size can grow up fast, maybe have a look at [upx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPX) executable compressor,
compressing the whole exe will compress his shipped data too, bitmap or raw will be crunched but still raw in your program

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this thorough guide. I'd +1'd for sure if only I was able to... Anyway, Thank you very much!