# converting png to c header for sdl

Tags: c, sdl, header-files

I want to say, I have searched in the internet about this topic, but it doesn't apply to my situation.

I was doing modifications for a game that uses C and I'm editing the images for use for the game, but the images needs to be converted to c headers to make them work. The game is multi-platform, with builds for Windows and Android via NDK.

I've actually accomplished some of the editing with "[Using .c/.h images exported with gimp in SDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149247/using-c-h-images-exported-with-gimp-in-sdl)" as my basis for my solution, using mbin2h, which converts any binary file into something that's fit for a C header. It worked for the Android build, but not for the main cross platform C build.

Here's an example code:

This is what mbin2h outputs usually:

```
0x89, 'P', 'N', 'G', 0xD, 0xA, 0x1A, 0xA, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xD, 'I', 'H', 'D', 'R'
```

Here's from the original source:

```
"\x89""PNG""\15\12\32\12\0\0\0\15""IHDR"
```

I don't know what program they used to convert the PNG to the header file. As some of you pointed out, it's a combination of hex, ASCII characters and octal values.

The question is how to convert the png to a header file similar to the original code? To make it easy for others to figure out, I've placed in the zip file the original image, the original header and the header generated by mbin2h: [image problem.zip - 319.73](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17441591/OpenBoR/image%20problem.zip)

This is actually for OpenBOR and I only wanted to modify the menu image, but because I don't know how to program that well, so I'm going to need some help, sorry about that.

**EDIT:** I didn't see that there's an answer button, I'll put the answer up. Sorry guys.

Comment: Suggest adding a question to the post.

Comment: "...using mbin2h and it worked." So what's the problem?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - Fixed the question, it worked on the android build, but not on the main builds including windows.

Comment: The to sets of data are basically equivalent.  If something doesn't understand one, that's irritating.  Note that the `"\x89""PNG"` notation is careful to ensure that the bytes after `\x89` are not interpreted as extra hex digits.  In this case, because `P` is not a hex digit, there'd be no problem, but if the word was `ABC` instead of `PNG` and the intermediate double quotes were omitted, then the hex escape would contain 89ABC and any other following hex digits (unlike an octal escape with is limited to 1-3 octal digits).

Comment: It wouldn't be particularly hard to write a Perl (Python, `awk`, …) script that converts the 'wrong' format into the right one.

Comment: @CRxTRDude Please describe what didn't work in your "main builds".

Comment: @Jonathan - It would be nice if there was some script, can it be done on shell scripts or is it only on python? I know a little python, having asking a python question years back.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - The main builds gives off errors like

`...
sdl/../resources/OpenBOR_Menu_320x240_png.h:11211: warning: initialization makes
 integer from pointer without a cast
sdl/../resources/OpenBOR_Menu_320x240_png.h:11211: error: initializer element is
 not computable at load time
...`

I actually replaced the ' to " and compiled it on the windows build.

Comment: @Jonathan: then again, a particular refinement here is that *octal* numbers also may be shorter than its max length. `\0\0` is shorter than its safer full form `\000\000` (and in hex you'd get an additional 2 characters). This program did miss the obvious `\15IHDR` though, it's only necessary to insert quotes when a digit < 8 follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting binary to C-compatible data is not *that* difficult, although I do wonder why the created structure is needlessly complex. Then again, if the rest of the source code expects this particular format, it's just a case of copying the original structure and filling in the right values.

> .. it's a combination of hex, ASCII characters and octal values ..

That would only be to make the source file as short as possible. There is no further reason; the entire image could be written out as `\x..` hex codes as well, or even decimals for that matter.

It was a nice additional challenge to make the header file as small as possible. Other than in the original, I made sure no single line exceeds 100 characters; still, by using more 'shortest alternatives', for the test image my code only produces 1,626 lines where the original has 1,921; 18% less!

Usage: programName input.png

It will replace the `.png` part of the input file with `.h` and write this output to the current folder. Works on OSX, and I guess it should compile on other *nix-like systems as well, as I tried to limit myself to Posix file I/O. Whether this does or does not include Windows is left as "exercise for the reader".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 100

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *f_in, *f_out;
    char *name_ptr,*ptr;
    off_t i;
    struct stat st;
    char out_name[FILENAME_MAX];
    unsigned char png_byte, last_byte_octal, output_length;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "this requires an input file\n");
        fclose (f_in);
        fclose (f_out);
        return -1;
    }

    f_in = fopen (argv[1], "rb");
    if (!f_in)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "this requires the input file to exist\n");
        fclose (f_in);
        fclose (f_out);
        return -1;
    }

    if (stat(argv[1], &st))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "this requires the input file to have no problems\n");
        fclose (f_in);
        fclose (f_out);
        return -1;
    }

    name_ptr = strrchr (argv[1], '/');      // *nix path
    if (!name_ptr)
        name_ptr = strrchr (argv[1], '\\'); // Wind*ws path
    if (name_ptr)
        name_ptr++;
    else
        name_ptr = argv[1];

    if (!*name_ptr || strlen(name_ptr) >= FILENAME_MAX)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "this requires a reasonable length for the file name\n");
        fclose (f_in);
        fclose (f_out);
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy (out_name, name_ptr);

    ptr = out_name;
    while (*ptr)
    {
        *ptr = tolower(*ptr);
        ptr++;
    }

    ptr = strrchr (out_name, '.');
    if (*ptr)
        strcpy (ptr, ".h");
    else
        strcat (out_name, ".h");

    f_out = fopen (out_name, "w");
    if (!f_out)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "this requires the output file to be created\n");
        fclose (f_in);
        fclose (f_out);
        return -1;
    }

    fprintf (stderr, "creating %s, please hold on.\n", out_name);


    ptr = out_name;
    while (*ptr)
    {
        if (*ptr == '.') *ptr = '_';
        ptr++;
    }

    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        fprintf (f_out, "#%s", !i ? "ifndef" : "define");
        fprintf (f_out, " _");
        ptr = out_name;
        while (*ptr)
        {
            fprintf (f_out, "%c", toupper(*ptr));
            ptr++;
        }
        fprintf (f_out, "_\n");
    }

    fprintf (f_out, "\n"
        "static const struct {\n"
        "\tsize_t size;\n"
        "\tunsigned char data [%lu];\n"
        "} ", (unsigned long)st.st_size);

    ptr = name_ptr;
    while (*ptr)
    {
        if (*ptr == '.')
            fprintf (f_out, "_");
        else
            fprintf (f_out, "%c", tolower(*ptr));
        ptr++;
    }

    fprintf (f_out, " = {\n"
        "\t%lu,\n\"", (unsigned long)st.st_size);

    last_byte_octal = 0;
    output_length = 1;
    for (i=0; i<st.st_size; i++)
    {
        png_byte = fgetc (f_in);
        if (png_byte == '\\')
        {
            output_length += 2;
            if (output_length >= MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
            {
                fprintf (f_out, "\"\n\"");
                output_length = 3;
            }
            fprintf (f_out, "\\\\");
            last_byte_octal = 0;
        }
        else if (png_byte == 9)
        {
            output_length += 2;
            if (output_length >= MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
            {
                fprintf (f_out, "\"\n\"");
                output_length = 3;
            }
            fprintf (f_out, "\\t");
            last_byte_octal = 0;
        } else if (png_byte < ' ' || png_byte == '\"')
        {
            output_length += (png_byte < 8) ? 2 : 3;
            last_byte_octal = 1;
            if (output_length >= MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
            {
                fprintf (f_out, "\"\n\"");
                output_length = (png_byte < 8) ? 3 : 4;
            }
            fprintf (f_out, "\\%o", png_byte);
        } else if (png_byte > '~')
        {
            output_length += 4;
            if (output_length >= MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
            {
                fprintf (f_out, "\"\n\"");
                output_length = 5;
            }
            fprintf (f_out, "\\x%X", png_byte);
            last_byte_octal = 1;
        } else
        {
            output_length += (last_byte_octal && isxdigit(png_byte)) ? 3 : 1;
            if (output_length >= MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
            {
                fprintf (f_out, "\"\n\"");
                output_length = 2;
                last_byte_octal = 0;
            }
            if (last_byte_octal && isxdigit(png_byte))
                fprintf (f_out, "\"\"");
            fprintf (f_out, "%c", png_byte);
            last_byte_octal = 0;
        }
    }
    fprintf (f_out, "\"\n};\n\n#endif\n");

    fclose (f_in);
    fclose (f_out);

    fprintf (stderr, "done.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can it be compiled via mingw? If that is so it may work on windows. I'll try this out.

Comment: It actually worked! I did compile it in Mingw and after that used it on a png and it worked! It is the same as the original code and more smaller.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked on other systems as well! The file could be made *slightly* smaller by using `\n` and `\r` (which are now represented in octal by `\12` and `\15`), and by checking the *next* character when writing out hex or octal, but it's just all cosmetic, and the final binary size will always be the same!

Comment: Oh, I thought this actually going to decrease the size as well... I got it now, since it compiles the same file anyway, it doesn't affect the size of the application at all. Btw, can I use the source for the development, how can I attribute you?

Comment: Any way you want -- [as you long as you mention Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/what-is-up-with-the-source-code-license-on-stack-overflow). See also the two links at the end of the longer line at the very bottom of this (and every other) page.

Comment: Okay, since this is general code, it might not be that much used during development, but I'll do attribution to Stack Overflow and you in the case that it would be added to our development. Again, thanks @Jongware !

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `mbin2h` is (even if I guess what it does). I suggest you to modify your build (e.g. your `Makefile`) to generate some `image.cdata` file with a command like perhaps

```
   mbin2h image.png > image.cdata
```

then have a C file containing (near its beginning, and with some other functions later)

```
   const char image_data[] = { 
   #include "image.cdata" 
   };
```

Then call appropriate routines using `image_data` and probably `sizeof(image_data)`; probably according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21151017/841108) something similar to

```
 SDL_RWops * z = SDL_RWFromMem(image_data,sizeof(image_data));
```

Of course that code should appear in the same C file as the `const char image_data[]` definition above (and *after* that definition).

PS. As [5gon12eder answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25709641/841108) you should prefer `hexdump` to your `mbin2h`

Comment: mbin2h is another program that converts binary files to C headers, it's created by another person, not me really. I just used it to convert the PNG to c header compatible with OpenBOR's android port.

The program was suggested on the [Stackoverflow question that i posted above.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149247/using-c-h-images-exported-with-gimp-in-sdl?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks! I might not used your method, but it inspired me to lead to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @BasileStarynkevitch's answer and in reply to your comment asking for “a script”: You can generate said include file `image.cdata` eg using the Posix `hexdump` utility.  In your makefile:

```
image.cdata: image.png
    hexdump --format='8/1 " 0x%02x," "\n"' $< > $@
```

The hex format is certainly not the most space efficient one.  Read [`man hexdump`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/hexdump1.html) if you feel an urge to improve this.

Comment: Supplemented what you said, this is actually similar to what mbin2h would put out, except that it also gives off the array size as well. Thanks for supplementing @5gon12eder ! You actually gave me the idea to the solution

Answer (score 0):

I solved it at last! As suggested by @Basile and @5gon12eder, I used what I did similarly in the android build:

```
char openbor_menu_480x272_png[32851]={
    ...
};
```

I declared it as char and added the array size to it. The `...` is the output of mbin2h. The hexdump method also works too, but you may need to calculate the array size manually.

I then found the code used to decode the header to image in the OpenBOR code and did so:

```
// Read Logo or Menu from Array.
if(!type)
    bgscreen = pngToScreen(isWide ? (void*) openbor_logo_480x272_png.data : (void*) openbor_logo_320x240_png.data);
else
    //CRxTRDude - Removed '.data' since it doesn't use it anyway.
    bgscreen = pngToScreen(isWide ? (void*) openbor_menu_480x272_png : (void*) openbor_menu_320x240_png);
```

I didn't edit the logo picture, so it stays as such.

Compiled it and it works! Apparently, since the android and the cross-platform builds all use the same PNG decoder, it actually did the job too.

But it just so happened that @Jongware actually made a C script that actually looked similar to the c header of the original and works! He also said that the reason that it's like that is for the sake of size, this gives off a smaller output than what mbin2h actually does.

> "Other than in the original, I made sure no single line exceeds 100
>   characters; still, by using more 'shortest alternatives', for the test
>   image my code only produces 1,626 lines where the original has 1,921;
>   18% less"

He was true though for one thing, the size of the header did reduce to 18%, but when it compiled though, the apk size didn't change though, but it's nice to note that this actually did a good job as well to replicate the original code and made it fractionally smaller.

Anyways, thanks guys for answering and I'm sorry if I'm misunderstood that much.